# Menu de opções com botão direito do mouse em linha selecionada em datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview

Olá, estou com o seguinte problema: tenho vários registros em `datagrid` e quero que no momento em que eu selecionar um registro e clicar com o botão direito do mouse sobre ele, apareça um menu com opções para a linha selecionada. As únicas opções desse menu é excluir, detalhes e imprimir. Tentei uma solução que me passaram outra pergunta que fiz, mas não deu certo, por ela habilitar o menu em qualquer lugar da `datagrid` que eu clicasse com o botão direito do mouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que o *ContextMenu* só apareça quando uma linha estiver seleccionada acrescente este *ItemContainerStyle* ao seu *ContextMenu*

```
<ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItems.Count}" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItems.Count}" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
```

O mais correcto seria o *ContextMenu* aparecer com os seu itens desabilitados:

```
<ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItems.Count}" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItems.Count}" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Não funcionou, na parte "Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItems.Count" aparece esse alerta: "Cannot resolve property "SelectedItems" in data context of type "System.Windows.UIElement" :(

Comment: Isso acontece porque por vezes em *design mode* ele não consegue seguir o *path*. Execute o programa ele deve funcionar.

Comment: Olha como ficou após adicionar: http://postimg.org/image/e8bhlhdeb/ e http://postimg.org/image/skg16llw1/

Comment: Aquele rectângulo que aparece é o Menu? No teste que fiz o Menu não aparecia. Testei numa *ListBox* mas o resultado deveria se o mesmo na *DataGrid*

Comment: Sim, o retângulo é o que deveria ser do menu. Não entendi porque ficou assim. De qualquer forma, obrigado pela ajuda :)

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa criar um `ContextMenu` no seu datagrid e colocar nele as opções.
Fica mais ou menos assim:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid">
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
       <ContextMenu>
          <MenuItem Header="Excluir" Click="MenuItemExcluir_Click"/>
          <MenuItem Header="Detalhes" Click="MenuItemDetalhes_Click"/>
          <MenuItem Header="Imprimir" Click="MenuItemImprimir_Click"/>
       </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
</DataGrid>
```

Para cada ação desse menu vai ter um evento de Click, nele você será capaz de identificar qual item foi clicado e continuar processando o que você precisa fazer.

Comment: Desse jeito eu tinha feito. O que eu quero é que o menu apareça no momento em que eu selecionar uma linha e clicar com o botão direito sobre ela. Desse jeito ai, em qualquer lugar da datagrid que eu clicar com o botão direito, o menu aparece, independente da linha ta selecionada ou não.